# How to train a PyTorch model in TensorFlow.js?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js, onnx

I'm looking to export my PyTorch model into tensorflow.js and have the ability to finetune it in tensorflow.js.
To do this, I first convert PyTorch weights to ONNX, then to tensorflow, and finally use `tensorflowjs_converter` to convert to tensorflow.js. This results in an un-trainable model in TensorFlow.js. Is there any way to make this model trainable at one of these steps? The following is a minimal reproducible example.

First, defining a generic model and converting it in PyTorch:

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F


class ModelClass(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ModelClass, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(100, 10)
        self.fc2 = torch.nn.Linear(10, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.sigmoid(self.fc2(x))
        return x


model = ModelClass()

example_input = torch.randn((1, 100), requires_grad=True)
print(model(example_input))

input_names = ["input0"]
output_names = ["output0"]
dynamic_axes = {'input0': {0: 'batch'}, 'output0': {0: 'batch'}}

torch_out = torch.onnx.export(
    model, example_input, 'model.onnx', export_params=True, verbose=True, input_names=input_names,
    output_names=output_names, dynamic_axes=dynamic_axes, opset_version=10,
    operator_export_type=torch.onnx.OperatorExportTypes.ONNX)
```

Next, I use `onnx_tf` to convert from ONNX to TensorFlow.

```
import onnx
import tensorflow as tf
from onnx_tf.backend import prepare

onnx_model = onnx.load('model.onnx')
tf_model = prepare(onnx_model)

tf_model.export_graph('model')
```

Finally, I use `tensorflowjs_converter` to convert to tensorflow.js with the command

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_saved_model model model_tfjs
```

However, when loading this in tensorflow.js with `tf.loadGraphModel("model_tfjs/model.json")`, it becomes a `tf.FrozenModel` according to [tensorflow.js documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/conversion). The only way to have a trainable model is by `tf.loadLayersModel` which requires a Keras model to be converted to tensorflow.js rather than a tensorflow savedmodel. However, I'm also unable to convert the converted tensorflow savedmodel into Keras. Is it possible to export a PyTorch model to tensorflow.js and have it still be trainable?

I've tried other libraries, `pytorch2keras`, `onnx2keras`, among others; they all seem to use lambda layers and therefore cannot be converted to tensorflow.js either. Thanks.

Edit: Here are additional details. I'm trying to convert an efficientnet from Pytorch to Tensorflow.

This converts the PyTorch efficientnet (from a library called geffnet) to ONNX. We can set either dynamic dimensions or static, but neither work.

```
import onnx
import geffnet
import torch

efficientnet = 'efficientnet_b0'
DYNAMIC_SIZE = True

img_sizes = [224, 240, 260, 300, 380, 456, 528, 600, 672]
model_idx = int(efficientnet[-1]) # to find the correct static image size 

model = geffnet.create_model(
    efficientnet,
    in_chans=3,
    pretrained=True,
    exportable=True)

model.eval()

example_input = torch.randn((1, 3, img_sizes[model_idx], img_sizes[model_idx]), requires_grad=True)
model(example_input)

input_names = ["input0"]
output_names = ["output0"]
dynamic_axes = {'input0': {0: 'batch'}, 'output0': {0: 'batch'}}
if DYNAMIC_SIZE:
    dynamic_axes['input0'][2] = 'height'
    dynamic_axes['input0'][3] = 'width'

torch_out = torch.onnx.export(
    model, example_input, 'efficientnet_b0.onnx', export_params=True, verbose=False, input_names=input_names,
    output_names=output_names, dynamic_axes=dynamic_axes,
    opset_version=11, operator_export_type=torch.onnx.OperatorExportTypes.ONNX)

onnx_model = onnx.load('efficientnet_b0.onnx')
onnx.checker.check_model(onnx_model)
```

Next, we can convert to Tensorflow.

```
import onnx
from onnx_tf.backend import prepare

onnx_model = onnx.load(onnx_path)
tf_model = prepare(onnx_model)
tf_model.export_graph('efficientnet_b0_tf')
```

Finally we convert to tensorflow.js using tfjs converter.

`tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tensorflow_saved_model efficientnet_b0_tf efficientnet_b0_tfjs`

A minimal test in tensorflow.js is as follows

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');

const getModel = async function () {
    const imgBase = await tf.loadGraphModel('file://./efficientnet_b0_tfjs/model.json');
    const x = tf.randomNormal([1, 224, 224, 3]);
    console.log(imgBase(x));
}
getModel();
```

The preceeding example works as a `tf.FrozenModel` in inference, but cannot be trained. To be trained, a model must be converted to tensorflow.js from keras. My attempts to convert the python tensorflow model to keras have been unsuccessful. For example,

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('efficientnet_b0_tf')
print(model.summary())

model.save(savepath)
```

This results in the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "graph2layers.py", line 29, in <module>
    graph2layers()
  File "graph2layers.py", line 18, in graph2layers
    print(model.summary())
AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'summary'
```

Comment: Do you need to use TensorFlow.js, would you accept another solution that allows you to train the model in JavaScript?

Comment: This particular question was directed at TF.js but definitely curious about other methods to train models in JavaScript w/ GPU support

Comment: Sweet. We were looking for ways to train models originally from PyTorch in JavaScript to facilitate Federated Learning. We looked into the things you mentioned but ran into the same limitations. We put together a few ideas from others and eventually hacked together a prototype to make an ONNX gradient graph from a PyTorch model, then use that gradient graph in an InferenceSession in JavaScript. I'm putting together all the ideas into a tutorial, here's a sneak peek https://github.com/juharris/train-pytorch-in-js/tree/init

Comment: Nice! That looks great. Thanks for sharing

Comment: I got the "PyTorch model" training using ONNX Runtime Web to work with MNIST digits. The tutorial is at https://github.com/juharris/train-pytorch-in-js. You can run it in your browser at https://juharris.github.io/train-pytorch-in-js.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure [pytorch2keras](https://pypi.org/project/pytorch2keras/) does not work? You could try saving the model in the `h5` format like the code below, which produces a `tf.Model`.

**Saving the model:**

```
import torch
from pytorch2keras.converter import pytorch_to_keras

net = # your model
x = torch.randn(1, 3, 224, 224, requires_grad=False) # dummy input
k_model = pytorch_to_keras(net, x, [(3, None, None,)], verbose=True, names='short')
k_model.save('keras.h5')
```

**Converting the model:**

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format keras \
                        <path-to-keras-model> \
                        <name-of-the-folder-to-save-js-model>
```

**Loading the LayersModel:**

```
const modelJson = require('<path-to-model.json>')
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(modelJson)
```

Comment: Gave this a shot, thanks. Unfortunately, converting to tensorflow.js, it introduces Lambda layers, which cannot be converted to tensorflow.js. To be more specific, I am trying to convert an efficientnet into tensorflow.js. I have edited the question to add more details. Thanks!

Comment: @StanleyZheng I see, hmm I know this isn't what you want but why not just use the Tensorflow equivalent and convert that to Tensorflowjs?

Comment: It's a bit unfortunate... But the tensorflow version of Efficientnet, `tf.keras.applications.efficientnet`, uses Rescale and Normalize preprocessing layers, which aren't implemented in tensorflow.js. I guess there's no easy way out than implementing these two layers then, thanks for your help @yudhiesh.